# Error when using the SoftLayer Ruby API to specify a flavor

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a working ruby script that we have been using for a quite a while to order VSIs from SoftLayer.  The script specifies a certain price item for CPU, one for memory, and another for disk.  I am trying to modify the script to work with flavors but I have been unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.  Basically I have removed the CPU, memory, and disk price items from the product order and added in a flavorKeyName in the supplementalCreateObjectOptions like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'softlayer_api'

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: 'XXXXX', api_key: 'XXXXX')

 productOrder = {
  'virtualGuests' => [{
     'hostname' => 'test',
     'domain'   => 'mycompany.com',
     'primaryNetworkComponent' => { 'networkVlan' => { 'id' => XXXXXX } },
     'primaryBackendNetworkComponent' => { 'networkVlan' => { 'id' => XXXXXX },
     'supplementalCreateObjectOptions' => { 'flavorKeyName' => 'B1_1X2X100' } }
  }],
  'location' => XXXXXX,
  'packageId' => 46,
  'imageTemplateId' => XXXXX,
  'useHourlyPricing' => true,
  'prices' => [
     {'id' => 34183 }, # 0 GB Bandwidth
     {'id' => 24713 }, # 1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks
     {'id' => 34807 }, # 1 IP Address
     {'id' => 33483 }, # Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
     {'id' => 34241 }, # Host Ping and TCP Service Monitoring
     {'id' => 32500 }, # Email and Ticket
     {'id' => 35310 }, # NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING
     {'id' => 23070 }, # REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE
     {'id' => 32627 }  # AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION
  ]
 }
 order = client['Product_Order'].verifyOrder(productOrder)
```

but this fails with:

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/xmlrpc/client.rb:271:in `call': Internal Error (XMLRPC::FaultException)
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/softlayer_api-3.2.2/lib/softlayer/Service.rb:269:in `call_softlayer_api_with_params'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/softlayer_api-3.2.2/lib/softlayer/Service.rb:198:in `method_missing'
    from /tmp/yy2:34:in `<main>'
```

The error is not too helpful on what I might be specifying incorrectly or might be missing.

Does any one have a suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [Softlayer_Product_Order::verifyOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder) or [Softlayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) you need to use the package 835, and set the **presetId** parameter to specify what flavor configuration you want to order.

The **supplementalCreateObjectOptions** parameter is specified when using the [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/createObject) method.

Following are two ways to order virtual guest devices with a flavor configuration.

**PlaceOrder**

To get the list of available preset ids for package 835 you need to use the method [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getActivePresets](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_product_package/getactivepresets).

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/835/getActivePresets
```

Check the **keyName** values to know which are Balanced, Memory, etc., they should start with:

> **B1**   is for "Balanced"
>
> **BL1**  is for "Balanced Local Storage"
>
> **BL2**  is for "Balanced Local Storage - SSD"
>
> **C1**   is for "Compute"
>
> **M1**   is for "Memory"

These characters are followed by a short description of VSI configuration as following:

> **C1_2X2X100**    for Compute VSI with "2 x 2.0 GHz Cores, 2 GB RAM, 100 GB Disk"
>
> **B1_8X16X25**    for Balanced VSI with "8 x 2.0 GHz Cores, 16 GB RAM, 25 GB Disk"

If I'm not wrong the **presetId** 333 is for B1_1X2X100 which is the flavor configuration you want.

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'json'

# Your SoftLayer API username and API Key.
USERNAME = 'set-me'
API_KEY = 'set-me'

# Location where server will be provisioned.
location = 'AMSTERDAM03'

# The id of the SoftLayer_Product_Package, use the 835 for VSI Families.
package_id = 835

# Following is the preset id used to complete this example. 
preset_id = 333   # B1_1X2X100  (1 x 2.0 GHz Cores, 2 GB RAM, and primary disk of 25 GB)

# The number of servers you wish to order in this configuration.
quantity = 1

# Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest object. If you set quantity greater than 1 
# then you need to define one hostname/domain per server you wish to order.
virtual_guest = [
    {
        'hostname' => 'test-vsi', 
        'domain' => 'mycompany.com',
        'primaryNetworkComponent' => { 'networkVlan' => { 'id' => 11111 } },
        'primaryBackendNetworkComponent' => { 'networkVlan' => { 'id' => 22222 }}
    }
]

# Specify the item prices. Note that you don't need to specify the item price for 
# cpus, ram, and primary disk, and take into account that “Balanced Local Storage”
# and “Balanced Local Storage - SSD” requires a second disk, the system will select one
# if you don’t specify it. 
prices = [
    {'id' => 34183 }, # 0 GB Bandwidth
    {'id' => 24713 }, # 1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks
    {'id' => 34807 }, # 1 IP Address
    {'id' => 33483 }, # Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
    {'id' => 34241 }, # Host Ping and TCP Service Monitoring
    {'id' => 32500 }, # Email and Ticket
    {'id' => 35310 }, # NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING
    {'id' => 23070 }, # REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE
    {'id' => 32627 }  # AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION
]

# Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order object containing the order
# you wish to place.
order_template = {
    'quantity' => quantity,
    'location' => location,
    'packageId' => package_id,
    'presetId' => preset_id,    
    'imageTemplateId' => 1111111,
    'useHourlyPricing' => true,
    'prices' => prices,    
    'virtual_guest' => virtual_guest
}

# Declare the API client to use the SoftLayer_Product_Order API service
client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: USERNAME, api_key: API_KEY)
product_order_service = client.service_named('SoftLayer_Product_Order')

begin
  # verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with placeOrder()
  # when you're ready to order. 
  receipt = product_order_service.verifyOrder(order_template)
  puts JSON.pretty_generate(receipt)
rescue StandardError => exception
  puts "There was an error in your order: #{exception}"
end
```

**CreateObject**

Take account that **createObject** method is a simplified way to order virtual guest devices so you may not be able to set items like IPV6, secondary IP address, etc. See [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/createObject) to know which properties you can set.

The following example is to order a vsi family with flavor configuration  B1_1X2X100, on this case it is necessary to set the parameter **supplementalCreateObjectOptions**

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'json'

# Your SoftLayer API username and API Key.
USERNAME = 'set-me'
API_KEY = 'set-me'

# Build the skeleton of SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest object.
virtual_guest_template = {
    'hostname' => 'test-vsi',
    'domain' => 'mycompany.com',
    'primaryNetworkComponent' => { 'networkVlan' => { 'id' => 11111 } },
    'primaryBackendNetworkComponent' => { 'networkVlan' => { 'id' => 22222 }},
    'datacenter' => { 'name' => 'dal05' },
    'supplementalCreateObjectOptions' => {
        'flavorKeyName' => 'B1_1X2X100'
    },
    'hourlyBillingFlag' => true,
    # Following is to specify the imageTemplate you want to use. But on this case you need
    # to set the globalIdentifier of imageTemplate.
    'blockDeviceTemplateGroup' => {      
      'globalIdentifier' => '6x06c3x8-4158-4b69-ba5x-433c18x3xac3'
    },
    'networkComponents' => [
        { 'maxSpeed' => 1000}   # 1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks
    ]
}

# Declare the API client to use the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest API service
client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: USERNAME,  api_key: API_KEY)
virtual_guest_service = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest']

begin
  # Call to createObject() when you're ready to order. 
  # Call to generateOrderTemplate() if you want to create an order container that can be
  # used with the methods verifyOrder and  placeOrder. 
  virtual_guest = virtual_guest_service.createObject(virtual_guest_template)
  puts JSON.pretty_generate(virtual_guest)
rescue StandardError => exception
  puts "There was an error in your order: #{exception}"
end
```